# Flex Type Ahead DropDownList

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, adobe

I need to implement multi character type ahead functionality on a DropDownList. Im using spark components Flex 4.5.1.

I wish the long list to for example if I type bl

It will go to Blue not to the first B then the first L

Its a common requirement and all browsers now support it, hope its something that already exists or someone has customized a version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use the Flex [Spark ComboBox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS70f0d54f063b9b081aac8d1d1247252e4a0-8000.html), which has the type ahead feature built right in?

Comment: I wasnt aware of that but was hoping for that kind of answer, let me investigate.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably customize one of the many autocompletes. I posted the following snippet in another question on how to do an autocomplete.

```
package autoCompleteExample
{
import mx.collections.ICollectionView;
import mx.collections.IList;    
import spark.components.ComboBox;
import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

public class AutoCompleteExample extends ComboBox
{   
    override protected function textInput_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void{
        super.textInput_changeHandler(event);
        ICollectionView(dataProvider).refresh();
    }       
    override public function set dataProvider(value:IList):void{
        ICollectionView(value).filterFunction = defaultFilterFunction;
        super.dataProvider = value;
    }       
    private function defaultFilterFunction(item:Object):Boolean{
        return (textInput.text.toLowerCase() == String(item[labelField].toLowerCase()).substr( 0, textInput.text.length ));
    }
}
}
```

You can probably just change the text operation handler to select the first item AFTER the refresh. Not sure how well it would work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at adapting that for DropDownList

Comment: I dont think DropDownList has textInput_changeHandler so this solution probably wont work.

Comment: I think you're confused about the difference between AutoComplete and Type Ahead.  Here is my blog post on it (which includes a sample w/ the two approaches side by side): https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/11/The-Difference-Between-AutoComplete-and-LookAhead

Comment: I know the difference, that's why I said it could be "adapted" from an autocomplete component that already exists. I didn't realize that the spark combobox does it automatically so you don't need the autocomplete code at all.